# Rendering 3D points in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, 3d

I am using 3D map view in QGIS 3.4 and I have point data. On layer properties I have enabled 3D Renderer but the billboard rendering to point option does not seem to be there.

Does anyone know where I can find this?

Comment: Billboard rendering in 3D view worked fine in 3.10 but now in 3.12 does not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was not backported to 3.4.x LTR branch, but does currently exist in 3.10.x branch.

See the [comment here by its developer](https://ismailsunni.github.io/GSoC-2019/):

> Result: Rendering point 3D as a billboard support is added to QGIS
>   3.10

As well as the [commit for it on the QGIS Github](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/31308):

Note that there was no milestone, nor backport specified. This went into master over the summer and made it into 3.10 thereafter. According to the [QGIS Roadmap](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/getinvolved/development/roadmap.html), when 3.10 becomes LTR this February you will have the feature if you can't switch to stable now.

```
| Event | Latest | Long-Term Repo | Freeze Date | Week # | Weeks |  
| LR/PR | 3.12.0 |     3.10.3     | 2020-02-21  |    8   |   4   |
```